# I have a trouble with changing a placeholder color in mat-from-field

Tags: angular-material

I won't change the color of input placeholder text. It's in a mat-drawer-content. I tried a few ways to do that: adding a new class finding a path for this element in dev tools I have no problem with the background changing but the text color won't change at all.
I need a little guidance in it

html file

```
<div class="selected-column" style="height: 90%" fxFlex="10" fxFlex.xs="100">

        <mat-form-field style="width: 100px">
            <input matInput
                    placeholder="From Date"
                    [(ngModel)] = "dayStart"
                    [dpDayPicker]="config.global.datePickerConfig"
                    theme="dp-material" attachTo=".mat-form-field-wrapper"
                    (displayDate) = "dayStart"
            />


        </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

scss

```
.mat-form-field-wrapper {
color: red;
}


input.mat-input-element {
color: red;
}
.mat-input-element .mat-form-field-autofill-control .cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored .ng-untouched .ng-valid .ng-dirty {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Where is the tried code?

Comment: I added I try to use ::ng-deep as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible and Working Solution:

Set encapsulation to the None in an underlying component like:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Simple form field */
@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-overview-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,  <--- here
})
export class FormFieldOverviewExample {}
```

and CSS to use:

```
.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
   color: red !important; -- on focus event
}

.mat-form-field-label {
   color: red !important;  -- for default color
}
```

[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj18nx)

Comment: ViewEncapsulation.None save my day I've never used it before. Thank you for your help, I learn something new today :)

Comment: no other alternatives ? cause i cannot change Encapsulation

Comment: @AhammadaliPK You can use `::ng-deep` instead

Comment: @AhammadaliPK [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj18nx-puemt2) is a working demo:

Comment: thanks , looks okay , but was having an issue with ng2-flatpickr

Comment: @AhammadaliPK feel free to file a new question with minimal information